# How do I scope all devise routes by role?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I have different roles for my users. For example, one role is a manager, and another is an employee. I was able to setup different logins and registrations, but I want them to both have separate routes behind the login.

```
class Employee < User 
class Manager < User
```

Accessible by employees but not managers

```
/stock-plan
```

Accessible by managers but not employees

```
/salaries
```

Accessible by both

```
/my-salary
/my-team
```

How can I achieve this with devise?

I tried using authenticated, but I seem to get a routing error even though `rake routes` show that it's accessible.

```
authenticated :employees do
    resources :stock_plan 
  end
```

Comment: paste the routing error.

Comment: @seaify-Freelancer Ah, I found out that my authenticated line wasn't working because I was using plural for employees.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that `:employees` shouldn't be plural

```
authenticated :employee do
    resources :stock_plan 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for example for employees routes.

```
devise_for :users, path: 'employees', path_names: { sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout' }, controllers: { sessions: 'employees/sessions', passwords: 'employees/passwords', confirmations: 'employees/confirmations', registrations: 'employees/registrations', unlocks: 'employees/unlocks' }
```

Comment: This is just for re-mapping the devise routes. I'm trying to have certain routes available based on roles and require authentication based on the roles

Answer (score 0):

add this to your salaries controller

```
before_action :correct_role

private
  def correct_role
    unless current_user.type=="Manager"?
      flash[:danger] = "You have no access"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

I assume you have add 
`before_action :authenticate_user!` in your controller